# Page number using javascript on wickedpdf

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

This is my controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "my_pdf", # pdf will download as my_pdf.pdf
        :layout => 'pdf', # uses views/layouts/pdf.haml
        :margin => { :top => 30 },
        :header => {template: 'layouts/pdf_header.html'},
        :show_as_html => params[:debug].present? # renders html version if you set debug=true in URL
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I get my view perfect but without any page number in the header 
For page number I used this code

pdf_header.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function number_pages() {
        var vars={};
        var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
        var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
        for(var i in x) {
          var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
          for(var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="number_pages()">
    Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I checked this as pure html I get an error for `x` saying it is null.When I researched to what x was taking in,I realised that no params are being passed to the URL and hence the error,how do I pass params to the URL?Does it come directly?

Other things that I tried were

```
:header => {content: render_to_string(template: 'layouts/pdf_header.html')},
:header => {content: render_to_string(layout: 'pdf_header.html')},
```

But none worked.I know I can get page number directly using this

```
'[page] of [topage]'
```

but I want it for some other purpose..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer...
I had to reinstall wkhtmltopdf.
Download the latest version of the wkhtmltopdf from this site http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Next,just follow the instructions from the official site https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

Anyways this is my full working example

This is my controller

```
class PdfexampleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
  render :pdf => 'hello',
  :template => "pdfexample/index.html.erb",
  :margin => {:top => 36, :bottom =>45 },
  :footer => {
    :content => render_to_string(:template => 'pdfexample/footer.pdf.erb')
  }
)
  end
end
```

My index.html.erb

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
  </head>
  <body>
    Add some text here .........................................................................................
  </body>
 </html>
```

footer.pdf.erb

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
    <script>
      function number_pages() {
        var vars={};
        var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
        var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
        for(var i in x) {
          var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
          for(var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
        }
      }
    </script>

  </head>
 <body onload="number_pages()">
    Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
  </body>

</html>
```